# A very very strange error ClassCastException. PreparedStatement's setInt method

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc

Can anybody tell me why is this method not working?

```
String strQuery = "Insert Into cust_subs (CustomerId,SubscriptionId) Values (?,?)";
PreparedStatement objPreparedStatement = Utils.getPreparedStatement(objConnection, strQuery);
objPreparedStatement.setInt(2, currentSubscriptions.get(0) );
```

where `currentSubscriptions` is:

```
List<Integer> currentSubscriptions;
```

I get this error even though it is Integer list:-

> SEVERE: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Assume that connection object already exists. And i am very sure that `currentSubscriptions` is not null else i wouldn't have got this error. If instead of using `List` i hardcode like this:

```
objPreparedStatement.setInt(2,1);
```

It works. I have even printed the values of `List` using System.out.println and it's perfectly fine. They are integers only. Don't know why is it treating them as Strings. I have even tried `Integer.parseInt` on list's item. Still it gives me the same error. This is one of the funniest errors I have ever faced.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT :-

Atleast this should work. But even this is not working :-

```
  int intSubscriptionId = Integer.parseInt( currentSubscriptions.get(0).toString());

            objPreparedStatement.setInt(2, intSubscriptionId );
```

**EDIT 2:**

Posting whole code :-

```
package beans;

import entities.Customer;
import entities.Subscription;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Savepoint;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import misc.Utils;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AddSubscriptionBean implements Serializable {

    private Customer customer;
    private List<Integer> currentSubscriptions;
    private List<Subscription> subscriptionList;

    public List<Subscription> getSubscriptionList() {
        return subscriptionList;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionList(List<Subscription> subscriptionList) {
        this.subscriptionList = subscriptionList;
    }

    public List<Integer> getCurrentSubscriptions() {
        return currentSubscriptions;
    }

    public void setCurrentSubscriptions(List<Integer> currentSubscriptions) {
        this.currentSubscriptions = currentSubscriptions;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    /** Creates a new instance of AddSubscriptionBean */
    public AddSubscriptionBean() throws IOException, SQLException {

        Connection objConnection = null;
        try {
            HttpServletRequest objHttpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            int intCustomerId = Integer.parseInt(objHttpServletRequest.getParameter("cid"));
            String strQuery = "Select * from customer Where CustomerID = " + intCustomerId;

            ResultSet objResultSet = Utils.executeResultSet(objConnection, strQuery);
            if (objResultSet.next()) {
                String strFirstName = objResultSet.getString("FirstName");
                String strLastName = objResultSet.getString("LastName");
                customer = new Customer(intCustomerId, strFirstName, strLastName);
            }

            currentSubscriptions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (Subscription objSubscription : customer.getSubscriptionList()) {
                currentSubscriptions.add(objSubscription.getSubscriptionId());
            }


            subscriptionList = new ArrayList<Subscription>();
            strQuery = "Select * from subscription";
            objResultSet = Utils.executeResultSet(objConnection, strQuery);
            while (objResultSet.next()) {
                int intSubscriptionId = objResultSet.getInt("SubscriptionId");
                String strSubsriptionTitle = objResultSet.getString("Title");
                String strSubsriptionType = objResultSet.getString("Type");
                Subscription objSubscription = new Subscription(intSubscriptionId, strSubsriptionTitle, strSubsriptionType);
                subscriptionList.add(objSubscription);
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.jsf");
        } finally {
            if (objConnection != null) {
                objConnection.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void save() throws SQLException {

        Connection objConnection = null;
        Savepoint objSavepoint = null;
        try {
            objConnection = Utils.getConnection();
            objConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            objSavepoint = objConnection.setSavepoint();
            String strQuery = "Delete From cust_subs Where CustomerId = " + customer.getCustomerId();

            if (!Utils.executeQuery(objConnection, strQuery)) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            strQuery = "Insert Into cust_subs (CustomerId,SubscriptionId) Values (?,?)";


            int intCustomerId = customer.getCustomerId();
            PreparedStatement objPreparedStatement = Utils.getPreparedStatement(objConnection, strQuery);
            for (int intIndex = 0; intIndex < currentSubscriptions.size(); intIndex++) {
                objPreparedStatement.setInt(1, intCustomerId);
                int intSubscriptionId = Integer.parseInt( currentSubscriptions.get(0).toString());

                objPreparedStatement.setInt(2, intSubscriptionId );
                objPreparedStatement.addBatch();
            }

            objPreparedStatement.executeBatch();

            objConnection.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (objConnection != null) {
                objConnection.rollback(objSavepoint);
            }
        } finally {
            if (objConnection != null) {
                objConnection.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my JSF page :-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:msc="http://mscit/jsf">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <center>
            <h:form>
            <h1>Add Subscription</h1>

            <b> Customer Name :</b> <h:outputText value="#{addSubscriptionBean.customer.firstName} #{addSubscriptionBean.customer.lastName}"/>

            <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{addSubscriptionBean.currentSubscriptions}">

                <f:selectItems value="#{addSubscriptionBean.subscriptionList}" var="row" itemLabel="#{row.title}" itemValue="#{row.subscriptionId}" />

            </h:selectManyCheckbox>

            <h:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{addSubscriptionBean.save}"/>
            </h:form>
        </center>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Please look at the h:selectManyCheckbox of JSF. JSF internally passes all the checkboxes that i have checked to my List. I think JSF is converting my integer list to string.

Comment: Is `setInt` actually where your error is occurring? `PreparedStatement.setInt` has only one overload, taking two integer arguments; your `List.get` should autounbox and it should work fine. But what about `Utils.getPreparedStatement`? Is that a custom method, or in a custom library? Searching for that specific static method on Google only returns this page.

Comment: What does `currentSubscriptions.get(0).getClass().getName()` return?

Comment: @Paul, `currentSubscriptions.get(0)` will cause a `ClassCastException`.  He needs to assign to a `List`, as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: Hi Brian, yes that is just my custom method. I found the problem but not the solution.

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to instruct `h:selectManyCheckbox` to convert the values to `Integer` by specifying `javax.faces.Integer` as converter. Generic types are namely unknown in EL and it treats the parameters by default as `String`.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox converter="javax.faces.Integer">
```

No need to use `List<String>` instead which would only lead to more weaktype clutter in the bean.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to put Strings into a `List<Integer>` if you use unsafe operations:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List list = intList;
list.add("1");
```

`intList` and `list` hold references to the same list, which now contains a string.  As you've seen, you get a `ClassCastException` upon trying to extract the element from `intList`.

Java generics work using hidden casting, and you can defeat the type-checking.  To test this, assign to a `List`, then print the class of every element:

```
List currentSubscriptionsUnsafe = currentSubscriptions;
for(Object o : currentSubscriptionsUnsafe)
{
  System.out.println(o.getClass());
}
```

**EDIT**: I'm not familiar with JSF, but I think your guess is correct.  One solution is to make `currentSubscriptions` a `List<String>` everywhere (which JSF seems to expect).  Then, `get(0)` will return a `String`, which you can parse into an `Integer`.  There may be a cleaner method, but this should work.

Comment: But i am not doing any such thing. How do i get rid of this? What changes do i need to make instead of list?

Comment: @Nitesh, print the class of every element using that code.  That will tell you if this is the issue.

Comment: Hi Matthew, Yes indeed this is the problem. I get this :- `INFO: class java.lang.String`. How can i solve this? Why is it being oversmart? even though i pass integers in it?

Comment: @Nitesh, post more of your code (anything somehow connected to `currentSubscriptions`).  You clearly have an unsafe reference somewhere, and you are adding a String using that.

Comment: Hi Matthew Flaschen, please read my edited post. Atleast the `edited` code should work? But even that is not working.

Comment: @Nitesh, no.  Because `currentSubscriptions` is a `List<Integer>` reference, `get(0)` has a hidden cast to `Integer`.  So you're trying to cast a `String` to an `Integer`, then call `toString`.  But the cast is still not allowed.  You need to prevent the `String` from being added in the first place.  Please show more code, specifically any code related to this list.

Comment: Great! Works :). But i still didn't understand your above comment Integer.parseInt will return a primitive type value and it is always a int only. Don't know why just changing List from Integer to String works.

Comment: He is refering to currentSubscriptions.get(0), not parseInt. The get method will try to convert the String's in your List to integers, which it cannot do. So making the list List<String> and calling get on the list will not try to convert to Integers.

Comment: @BobTurbo, i was talking about my edited code. Can you tell me how can this ever return anything other than int? `int intSubscriptionId = Integer.parseInt(currentSubscriptions.get(0).toString());`? I always thought Integer.parseInt will always return a primitive type `int`. No matter what the internal references are but Integer.parseInt should always return a primitive `int` type value. I must admit this is one of the most strange errors i have faced till today and not easy for me to digest.

Comment: It will always return an int, but int intSubscriptionId = Integer.parseInt(currentSubscriptions.get(0).toString()); is now where the error occurs (instead of the next line). As the error is in currentSubscription.get(0). So you have just shifted the error up a line.

Comment: @Nitesh, when `currentSubscriptions` was a `List<Integer>`, that line internally became: `int intSubscriptionId = Integer.parseInt(((Integer)(currentSubscriptions.get(0))).toString());`.  You were still casting a `String` to an `Integer`, which is an error.

Comment: Thanks Matthew Flaschen. Got it!

Comment: While technically correct, the proposed solution is in JSF context not a real solution but more a workaround. I certainly wouldn't use it.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for your valuable comments. Did you later on happen to give a thought on creating JSF composite components using JQuery? Netbeans 6.9 is out and it's fine.